# Android app include 2 different languages

Tags: android

I am new in Android app developers.I want to create an app based on the content of a book.But the book include 2 different languages.App must be in The same languages and fonts..

So how can i include that language and fonts in my app?? 
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put xml with string in specific dir. Read more here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

For front it will be better with custom text view:

```
/** * TextView with custom font
*/
public class TextViewWithFont extends TextView {
private final String FONT = "fonts/Verdana.ttf";

public TextViewWithFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), FONT));
    }
public TextViewWithFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), FONT));
    }
public TextViewWithFont(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), FONT));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add fonts, read --> [this](http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html).

The languages can be added creating a values-xx.xml for every language.. like this:

```
MyProject/
    res/
       values/
           strings.xml
       values-es/
           strings.xml
       values-fr/
           strings.xml
```

(values without sufix are in English)

In every file, the syntax has to be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">My app name</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a general folder for your project resources and then some language specific.

The general folder is at Project-->res-->values.
This folder can contain files such as strings.xml,fonts.ml, colors.xml,dimens.xml,etc.

Along with the above general folder you could also support other languages by providing a language specific folder.consider if i choose spanish.
I would have a folder Project-->res-->values-es. ("es" for spanish,"en" for english, etc.)
This folder,"values-es" would also have the files strings.xml,fonts.ml, colors.xml,dimens.xml,etc.,

Now the access to these files would be governed by the user locale.
If the user has locale as "es" then the files in "values-es" would be checked for the value.If the value is found it would be returned, else the default "values" folder would be checked.
If the user has locale whose specific values folder is not defined the default"values " folder would be used to check the value. i.e. if my locale is japanese and i only have "values" and "values-es" folders i would be given values from "values " folder.

Your case: you should have a single fonts folder in "values". no need for another one. one should suffice. however for strings you should have two strings file one each in "values" and "values-??".